# Why Will This Compile in Visual Studio 2012 But Not UNIX?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int length = 0;

cout << "Enter a string: ";

string buffer;
char buff[1024];

while (getline(cin, buffer)) 
{
    buffer.erase(remove_if(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), not1(ptr_fun(isalnum))), buffer.end());
    break;
}

length = buffer.length();
int squareNum = ceil(sqrt(length));

strcpy(buff, buffer.c_str());

char** block = new char*[squareNum];
for(int i = 0; i < squareNum; ++i)
block[i] = new char[squareNum];

int count = 0 ;

for (int i = 0 ; i < squareNum ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < squareNum ; j++)
    {
        block[i][j] = buff[count++];
    }
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < squareNum ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < squareNum ; j++)
    {
        cout.put(block[j][i]) ;
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Errors:

```
asst4.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
asst4.cpp:30:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘ptr_fun()’
asst4.cpp:30:76: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:443:5: note: template std::pointer_to_unary_function std::ptr_fun(_Result (*)(_Arg))
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:469:5: note: template std::pointer_to_binary_function std::ptr_fun(_Result (*)(_Arg1, _Arg2))
asst4.cpp:37:29: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Presumably you're passing that `std=c++11` flag or whatever it is. And using an up-to-date compiler.

Answer (score 4):

`std::strcpy` is in the `cstring` header, that should be included.

`std::isalnum` is also in the `locale` header and `std::ptr_fun` cannot choose one, that you need. You should specify it manually like

```
std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isalnum))
```

or cast `std::isalnum` to needed signature

```
std::not1(std::ptr_fun(static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isalnum)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `strcpy` problem, use e.g. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead, or include `<cstring>` which contains the prototype for `strcpy`.

Not that you really *need* that temporary `buff` variable as you can use e.g. `buffer[count++]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcpy` error is obvious -- just `#include <cstring>`

For the `ptr_fun()` error, my guess is that your `using namespace std` is causing it to try to use one of the templated versions of `std::isalnum` from the `<locale>` header. Simply changing the call to

```
not1(ptr_fun(::isalnum))
```

makes it compile happily with both g++ and clang on my system.